# Calculating the length of an array of regular expressions

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a function here that is meant to check an element against a given array of regular expressions. The array that I am passing contains ten different regular expressions.

```
var regExAlphabet = /[a-z]/;
var regExNumbers = /[0-9]/;
var regExWhile = /while/;
var regExIf = /if/;
var regExElse = /else/;
var regExTrue = /true/;
var regExFalse = /false/;
var regExInt = /int/;
var regExString = /string/;
var regExBoolean = /boolean/;

var regexList = [regExAlphabet, regExNumbers, regExTrue, regExFalse,
regExInt, regExString, regExBoolean, regExWhile, regExIf, regExElse];

function loopThroughOptions(regexList, element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < regexList.length; i++)
    failSafe(regexList[i], element) // failSafe is defined but not shown
}

var aString = "a";

loopThroughOptions(regexList, aString);
```

When I run this, I am getting an uncaught typeError: cannot read property length of undefined in my loopThroughOptions function. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

EDIT: It looks like I will need to post the failSafe function. It is quite long. Take a stab at it.

```
var tokenList = []; // list of discovered tokens
var substringsArray = []; // any strings that are not tokens go here

    function substringsHandler(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < substringsArray.length; i++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < regexList.length; y++) {
      failSafe(regexList[y], substringsArray[i])
    }
  }
}    

function findAMatch(value) {
    if (value == "a")
        console.log("matched a");
}

function findACharMatch(value) {
    if (value == "a")
        console.log("matched a");
}

function failSafe(regEx, element) {

  if (regEx.test(element) && element.length > 1) { // if the token is there
    var x = regEx.exec(element); // give us more information on the element
    var value = x["0"]; // keep track of the value of the token
    var index = x.index; // keep track of the index
    var substring = value;
    console.log(index);
    console.log(substring.length);
    console.log(element.length);
    tokenList.push({
      value: substring,
      indexFound: index});
    console.log(tokenList[0]);
    if (index > 0 && index + substring.length - 1 < element.length) { // if we found a token in the middle of a string
      console.log("Found token in the middle of the string.");
       substringsArray.push({ // give us the half that comes before the match
          value: element.substring(0, index),
          indexFound: 0
          });

       substringsArray.push({ // give us the rest of the string that occurs after the match
         value: element.substring(index + value.length),
         indexFound: index + value.length
         });

        substringsHandler(substringsArray);
         // all successful token finds get sent to tokenList to search for a match
         // if nothing is found, then everything gets translated to characters or digits
   }       else if (index > 0 && index + substring.length - 1 == element.length)   { // if there is more string to the left only
            console.log("Found token on the right of the string.");
           substringsArray.push({
           value: element.substring(0, index), // compare these values using   find a match later
           indexFound: 0
            })
    } else if (index == 0 && substring.length < element.length) { // if there is     more string to the right only
            console.log("Found token on the left of the string.");
           substringsArray.push({
            value: element.substring(substring.length),
            indexFound: substring.length
           })
    } else { // the token is the only input
        console.log("The token consists of the entire string.");
    }
  } else if (regEx.test && element.length == 1) {
      var x = regEx.exec(element); // give us more information on the element
      var value = x["0"]; // keep track of the value of the token
      var index = x.index; // keep track of the index
      var substring = value;
        tokenList.push({
          value: value,
          index: index
        })
    } else {
      console.log("No match for regexp " + regEx + "trying the next one...");
      return;
  }
  console.log(tokenList);
  tokenList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.indexFound - b.indexFound;
  });
  console.log(tokenList);
  for (var i = 0; i < tokenList.length; i++) {
    if (tokenList[i].value.length > 1)
      findAMatch(tokenList[i].value);
    else
      findACharMatch(tokenList[i].value);
  }
};
```

Comment: That code runs for me without issues.

Comment: I don't see a problem either, but it might be a scope issue. Also if you will always use 10 elements you could do until 10, or make a global variable that is var size = regexList.length; and iterate until i < size

Comment: I don't get an issue too, but I might think that `failSafe` function does something to your array

Comment: Alan - I gave that a try, and get another error "cannot read property [0] of undefined", on my failSafe function call. Thoughts? Something weird is going on with my array.

Comment: My guess is the bug is in the failsafe function

Comment: Please post the failSafe function, this is not a "we're guessing what your not shown function does" game, but a "we help you with the code you've shown" one. The code you're showing runs without a problem, so the question should be closed as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Posted the failSafe function as requested

Comment: If you're writing a lexer/parser, you should be asking a specific question. I don't see a specific question here.

Comment: I can't really come up with a question that is more specific as "I am getting this error, but I shouldn't be, what could the cause be?" I am indeed writing a lexer. Some people suspect that the problem may be within the failSafe - so I guess my new question could be: "where in the failSafe function is the regular expression array being changed to undefined?"

Comment: I am not sure what it is that I can do to help. I came to you guys because I've been banging my head against the wall trying to debug this. Please, if there is anything more that I can do to help solve this, let me know and I will help.

Comment: This still isn't a complete example that someone else could run. For example, you use tokenList inside your failSafe function, but you never initialize it. Please review the guidelines on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any sub-routines called inside the function are now shown as well. The match functions are simplified. This is the best I can do, short of providing the entire source code.

Comment: Now, please tell me it wasn't all for nothing - gotta head out for dinner now.

Comment: is there a problem that arises when using regular expressions as elements in an array maybe? I really have no idea. I'm gonna comb through my code until I find a solution. This forum is useless for problems that extend below the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ran all of your showed code and it has an error, according to [RegExp docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

> If the match fails, the exec() method returns null.

So, in your code, you always take for granted that `regEx.exec(element);` will return an array (it supposes that the RegExp will match at least one element), which, at least in your examples, is false, and you are not handling that.

In short, the easiest way to get rid of this is by returning if `x` is null:

```
var x = regEx.exec(element);
if (!x) return // add this
```

Tested it, and no problem was thrown, only console output was `matched a`